# Конфигурация spring-webmvc.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Помогите сконфигурировать Spring.

Контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class IndexController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
...
```

Репозиторий

```
@Repository
public class JpaRepositoryImpl implements JpaRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager emf; // Для внедрения EntityManager
...
```

ну и куча остальных нужных классов

Репозиторий подключен в spring-db.xml

```
...
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.bityard.bitrix24.serverAuth.repository"/>
...
```

Контроллер и сервисы подключены в spring-mvc.xml

```
...

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.bityard.bitrix24.serverAuth.**.web"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.bityard.bitrix24.serverAuth.**.service"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
...
```

Все остальные бины я собираю в spring-app.xml

И вот все это я пытаюсь собрать воедино в web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-app.xml
            classpath:spring-db.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:spring-mvc.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
2019-05-25 11:48:00 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-4:DispatcherServlet.java:doService:891 - DispatcherServlet with name 'index' processing GET request for [/index.php]
2019-05-25 11:48:00 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-4:AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:getHandlerInternal:312 - Looking up handler method for path /index.php
2019-05-25 11:48:00 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-4:AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:getHandlerInternal:322 - Did not find handler method for [/index.php]
2019-05-25 11:48:00 WARN  http-nio-8080-exec-4:DispatcherServlet.java:noHandlerFound:1205 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/index.php] in DispatcherServlet with name 'index'
2019-05-25 11:48:00 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-4:FrameworkServlet.java:processRequest:1000 - Successfully completed request
```

Где у меня ошибка в конфигурации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне удалось решить проблему так:

файлы spring-db.xml и spring-mvc.xml я импортировал в spring-app.xml

**spring-app.xml**

```
...
    <import resource="spring-db.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-mvc.xml"/>
...
```

а настройку диспетчера сделал так

**web.xml**

```
... 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-app.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-despetcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
          <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:spring-app.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-despetcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
...
```

и комбайн завелся...

Answer (score 0):

Замените `@RequestMapping("/*")` на `@RequestMapping("/")` - звездочка лишняя.

Эту аннотацию перед методом лучше указывать, а не общую для всего класса.

А еще лучше перед методом написать:

```java
@RequestMapping({"/", "/index.html", "/index.php"})
```

---

См. [Spring RequestMapping](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping)

Comment: Да нет, дело не в этом, хотя, я попробовал как вы сказали. Дело в том, что если не заморачиваться в добавлении AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext и запустить только spring-mvc.xml, то вебсервер запускается и все запросы мапятся с теми настройками, что я указал. Проблема появляется как только я пытаюсь в диспетчер загрузить контекст спринга...

Comment: Я думаю, что у меня чего-то не хватает в web.xml для корректной конфигурации